# how to pass another parameter from jquery ajax to mvc controller, along with form.serialize()

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery, defaultmodelbinder

I use a jQuery plugin called jscroller, which uses jquery.ajax to make ajax calls.
I need to pass in all parameters from a search form, and deliver them to mvc controller, and I think the best way is to put in 'data' field the following expr':

```
$('#formId').serialize();
```

My problems is that I need to pass, along with the form values, a 'page' value which is being changed with each call.

How can I put the page value, along with the 'serialize' expression in 'data' field, or is there really another more efficient way to do it?

Comment: You can try to add a hidden input to the form (with the value you need)

Comment: I've tried that, and something goes wrong in the way.. I prefer not to..

Comment: Then try this: var form = $('#formId').serialize(); form.page = "otherparamentervalue";. Then send the form variable as data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
var formdata = $('#formId').serialize();
data: (formdata ? formdata + "&" : "") + "page=" + pageId
```

will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new FormData and just add the parameter on that variable too

```
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('pageId', pageId);

var your_form = $('#formId').serializeArray();
$.each(your_form,function(key,input){
   formData.append(input.name,input.value);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'url_here',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST'
});
```

so at MVC controller you will be able to access like

```
var pageId = Request.Form.Get("pageId");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super late but the code below worked for me.

```
var data = $('#Form').serialize() + '&test=' + number;
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: data;
```